# SSMS 2014 Design Does not show column

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I have created a table which has the columns

```
Id, name, CountryId,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,updatedOn,UpdatedBy
```

but when i see the design, there is no CountryId.

[image]

> When i see script of the created table, it shows CountryId

the script is as follows --

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
        [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
        [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    );
```

**Also, When I right click and select top 100 rows, i find CountryId there. (The following image)**

[image]

**What can be the reason that the design is not showing a column ??**

> **EDIT:**
>   **As suggested by [shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo), i was able to solve it  after closing and re-opening SSMS 2014**

Comment: Try re-opening the DESIGN view. I couldn't reproduce the issue and I used the code you provided. I'm also using SSMS 2014, version 12.0.2000.8 to be precise.

Comment: Did you try to right-click onto the `dbo,State` node of the tree view and refresh it?

Comment: yes, I tried refreshing the Db, but no luck @Shnugo

Comment: re-opening did not work @RaduGheorghiu

Comment: Shut down SSMS and re-open it?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get a clear answer and precise here, since the issue you're experiencing is not a general one and not one which can be reproduced easily (or in normal circumstances). And what we're doing now is just doing "caveman debugging" in terms of suggestions.

Comment: @Shnugo , awsome !! it worked after re-opening the SSMS :)

Comment: But what can be the reason which eliminated after re-opening the SSMS ?

Comment: @Shnugo suggested you to refresh the table, while you were trying to "refresh the db" - these are different object tree levels.

Comment: I refreshed the `Table` as suggested, but It did not work.

Comment: @DastagirHusainYasin why don't you upgrade to the *latest* version? SSMS is a separate product now, which can be downloaded for free. The latest version [came out today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , Thanks for the suggestion, I have downloaded it .